# How to open a batch program in fullscreen without scrollbar?

Tags: windows-10, batch

I want to make a batch file that opens in fullscreen as if you press Alt-Enter.
And i would like it without scrollbar too, but i haven't found anything on it.

I have heard you can use vbs to send button presses, but how would i do that?

**Remember i use Windows 10**

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I would like a batch file which opens in fullscreen (aka the Alt+Enter). Im currently searching for a way of removing the scrollbar.

Comment: Your way did not work, i tried `WshShell.SendKeys "%{ENTER}"` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) key to send would be <kbd>**F11**</kbd> rather than <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**Enter**</kbd> so below is an example logic batch script that open a CMD window, maximizes that window to full screen, and then runs some logic, etc.

I'm not certain there is a batch script solution available to make the command prompt scrollbar disappear but below is a method which will work on Windows 10 for making the command prompt (CMD) full screen with the scrollbar.

**Example Batch Script**

```
@ECHO OFF

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%temp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{F11}"                            >>"%TempVBSFile%
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"

:: Put whatever logic below for your script to run in the full screen CMD window
ECHO Logic is fun
ECHO Fun is Logic
ECHO Just logically fun
PAUSE
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**sendkeys**](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)
- [**cscript**](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html)