# Windows 7: Send 'save (all) file(s) command' to all opened programs

Tags: windows-7, batch

I was wondering if there's a native way to send or initiate the *save file* or even *save all files* command for all opened programs (or just a selection) in Windows 7 - preferably as batch file.

Maybe similar to [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156592.aspx) approach (Windows Script Host/WSH).

I'm not looking for a macro tool or any third-party utility, though. 
(I know there are plenty out there which might be even capable of doing the trick)

So far I could only find information about WSH (which I have no idea yet how to use it) or those external tools.

Comment: Jim - I've written many scripts that use dynamic VBS and SendKeys functions using batch that runs natively on Windows but when you say you need to use the **save** or **save as** functions **"for all opened programs"** then this gets difficult as each program may have different hotkeys that need press to perform this operation. See here for one of these scripts I've written as an example: http://superuser.com/questions/1107385/how-to-open-a-batch-program-in-fullscreen-without-scrollbar/1108032#1108032

Comment: Example 2: http://superuser.com/questions/1101434/in-firefox-is-there-a-counterpart-to-google-chromes-app-option/1101822#1101822 and Example 3: http://superuser.com/questions/1020871/make-pc-wake-up-using-task-scheduler-in-win-10-from-sleep/1020905#1020905